# downscale all images in a folder with imagemagick

Tags: linux, command, imagemagick

I am trying to downscale all images (JPG and PNG) in a specific folder using the following command:

I've tried:

```
mogrify -resize 600/> *.jpg
mogrify -resize 600/> *.JPG
mogrify -resize 600/> *.png
mogrify -resize 600/> *.PNG
```

Some images are getting erased down to 0kb.

Comment: Try reversing the direction of your slash.

Comment: @MarkSetchell so simple, thank you very much!